# How to document destructured function arguments? e.g. `a` when writing `const fn = ({a}) => {/* code */}`

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, destructuring

I write a lot of code like:

```
const MyFn = ({myInput}) => {
   // code
};
```

How should I document the type of those inputs?

If I weren't using destructuring, I'd write something like this:

```
/**
* @param {Number} myArg It's a number
*/
const MyFn = (myArg) => {
   // code
};
```

...And my IDE (VS Code) would pick that up and use it to make helpful suggestions.

What is the equivalent jsdoc for the destructured syntax of `({myInput})`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [*Documents with Properties*](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties):

> **Documenting a destructuring parameter**
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Assign the project to an employee.
>  * @param {Object} employee - The employee who is responsible for the project.
>  * @param {string} employee.name - The name of the employee.
>  * @param {string} employee.department - The employee's department.
>  */
> Project.prototype.assign = function({ name, department }) {
>     // ...
> };
> ```

Basically, you include a `@param` for the object/array and then a `@param` for what you're destructuring from it.

So applying that to your code:

```
/**
* @param {Object} thingy - The description for the object you're expecting
* @param {TypeForMyInput} thingy.myInput - The description of the destructured property
*/
const MyFn = ({myInput}) => {
   // code
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You also could use `@typedef` to do this.

[image]